# How to exclude a directory (not remove) when you are listing directories in python

Tags: python

I am using os.walk and i am able to successfuly list directories. I am using these directories as variable and i dont need couple of directories to be part of it. How do i exclude and have all the other directories to move forward ?

Comment: It would be a great help if you could share, at the very least, (a) your code, as you've currently got it, (b) the criteria on which folders you'd like to "exclude", and (c) your attempt to solve the problem at hand, along with where *specifically* you're getting stuck in said attempt (why your attempt does not meet your requirements).

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/test/wsx/xxxxx/myfile.txt'. Would like to remove this directory.   import os
import stat



for dirs in next(os.walk("/tmp/xxxx/"))[1]:
        file = "/tmp/test/{}/xxxx/myfile.txt".format(dirs)

        f = open(file, "x")
        print('Testing: {}'.format(file))

Comment: Unfortunately, your comment doesn't provide that much additional clarity. Among others, my ask above was that you provide the *criteria* for which you want to exclude certain directories.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `dirs` in-place will prune the (subsequent) files and directories visited by `os.walk`:

```
# exclude = set([...])
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=True):
dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in exclude]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by simply modifying i.e. by deleting your excluded directories from the `subdirectory list` `inplace(note this word)` which is yielded by `os.walk()`. You can do it several ways(i mean, the inplace deletion):

First write this on top of your code:

```
import os

root = "the/path/to/root/dir";
exclude_dir_set = set(['some_dir', 'another_some_dir`])
```

**First method**:

```
for current_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    dirs[:] = list(set(dirs) - exclude_dir_set)
```

**second method:**

```
for current_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    dirs[:] = [_dir for _dir in dirs if _dir not in exclude_dir_set]
```

**third method:**

```
for current_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for _dir in dirs:
        try:
            if _dir in exclude_dir_set:
                dirs.remove(_dir)
        except ValueError:
            pass # do nothing
```

If you've any question, pls ask in the comment...

Comment: receiving this error TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: root = "/tmp/xxxx/";
exclude_dir_set = set(['wsx'])


for dirs in next(os.walk(root))[1]:
 dirs[:] = list(set(dirs) - exclude_dir_set)
        file = "/tmp/test/{}/xxxx/myfile.txt".format(dirs)

        f = open(file, "x")
        print('Testing: {}'.format(file))

Comment: It works perfectly in my pc...well, why are you using `next(os.walk(root))`?

Comment: also, which line is giving you errro?

Comment: I guess, you've some problem with while `formatting file name`, pls check again and share update...